# Debugging Redux using Chrome Devtools in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, redux, google-chrome-devtools, redux-devtools

When using the `redux-devtools-extension` in my web app's codebase, I'm able to debug Redux actions and state changes in the browser.

If I run Node.js with `--inspect` and debug in Chrome, I expect to see the same behavior, but I only see the message:

> No store found. Make sure to follow the instructions.

How can I use Redux DevTools when doing Node.js development with `--inspect`?

Comment: Check this link for setting up dev tools - https://github.com/gaearon/redux-devtools#setup-instructions

Comment: That's the original devtools module, not the newer devtools-extension. It also doesn't list the solution I would like to see.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/zalmoxisus/remote-redux-devtools

`remote-redux-devtools` can be used for node.js